# Alexa can't find my own library on spotify

Tags: alexa, amazon-echo

I just bought an Echo Dot from Amazon, and added my spotify premium account to it but when I asked "Alexa, to play my library," it replied with "I can't find any music in your library." Is there anyway to fix this problem?

Comment: Have you tried asking for a playlist instead of generically for your library?